# Python Match Portion of File Name

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match file names within a folder using python so that I can run a secondary process on the files that match. My file names are such that they begin differently but match strings at some point as below:

3322_VEGETATION_AREA_2009_09
3322_VEGETATION_LINE_2009_09
4522_VEGETATION_POINT_2009_09
4422_VEGETATION_AREA_2009_09
8722_VEGETATION_LINE_2009_09
2522_VEGETATION_POINT_2009_09
4222_VEGETATION_AREA_2009_09
3522_VEGETATION_LINE_2009_09
3622_VEGETATION_POINT_2009_09

Would regex be the right approach to matching those files after the first underscore or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("*VEGETATION*")
```

should do the trick. It should find all files in the current directory that contain `"VEGETATION"` somewhere in the filename